# Change UIImageView image with swipe action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, swift2

On my tableview I have a UIImageView, and I need change the image when swipe action is executed. I have a class to row of tableview, so I changed the code to try do it. This is the code but not worked. How can I do it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CellTableViewFriends{  
    // you need to implement this method too or you can't swipe to display the actions  
    let cell = self.tableViewFriends.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTableViewFriends") as! CellTableViewFriends;  
    cell.imgArrow.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")  

    return cell  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's what you want to do, you should change:

```
let cell = self.tableViewFriends.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTableViewFriends") as! CellTableViewFriends;
```

to [cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:)

```
let cell = self.tableViewFriends.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your cell class, you can add the following methods:

```
func addSwipeGesture() {
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipedLeft))
        gestureRecognizer.direction = .Left
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func swipedLeft(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer!) {
        //Change picture here
        imgArrow.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
    }
```

You can change the direction or do the same for adding multiple directions.

Then you should make sure you call the addSwipeGesture command when creating the cell, you can do that in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should add swipegesture recognozer to custom cell class and and handle swipe from that class i think. `commitEditingStyle` is for editing cell like delete, so you can't use it to swape images in cell.

Hope this will help :)